# Interchange two columns

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to swap the "Hits" and "Domain" column.

`cat filename` Output:

```
  Hits          Domains
  204492        greenlivingasc.in
  37102         smcracks.uk
  17410         bahriains.org
  10975         cmhlahore.co.uk
  10342         albps.in
  9541          mediabites.co.uk
```

But when I used the following command to swap column, `awk '{ print $2 " " $1}' filename`, it outputs misaligned formatting:

```
 Domains    Hits       
 greenlivingasc.in 204492
 smcracks.uk 37102
 bahriains.org 17410
 cmhlahore.co.uk 10975
 albps.in 10342
 mediabites.co.uk 9541
```

I want to get proper alignment after swapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pipe it in a `column -t` the result, like :

```
awk '{ print $2 " " $1}' file.txt | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution like `column` mau help:

```
:~$ column -t 123
Hits    Domains
204492  greenlivingasc.in
37102   smcracks.uk
17410   bahriains.org
10975   cmhlahore.co.uk
10342   albps.in
9541    mediabites.co.uk
```

Another way is to use `expand`:

```
:~$ cat 123 | expand --tabs=10
Hits          Domains
204492        greenlivingasc.in
37102         smcracks.uk
17410         bahriains.org
10975         cmhlahore.co.uk
10342         albps.in
9541          mediabites.co.uk
```

OR try to change awk expression:

```
 cat 123 | awk -v cols=1 '{printf("%-44s",$0)} NR%cols==0 {print ""} END {print ""}'
```